# How to get private tweet in ios7?

Tags: twitter, ios7

I know there is lots of things given about twitter integration and private tweets.
But I want to know that if I use `TWRequest` in ios7 then it will work or not?

```
My code snippet as follows.
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if(granted)
        {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempDict setValue:@"rohit40793982" forKey:@"screen_name"];
                //[tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
                // [tempDict setValue:@"683286" forKey:@"user_id "];

                TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/snehalikanksha/status/388535072359317504.json"]
                                                             parameters:tempDict
                                                          requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];


                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",urlResponse);
                    NSArray  *tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                         error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"%@",tweets);
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"%@", output);
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];

                }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

Can anybody help me ?
It gives `Http` error 403.
and log shows

```
"Your account may not be allowed to perform this action. Please <a class=\"js-reload\" href=\"#\">refresh the page</a> and try again."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do but the reason why your code doesn't work is that you're not using a [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) endpoint.

If you want to get details for a specific tweet, you can use [GET statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid).

You would have to change your code for:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=388535072359317504"];

TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                         parameters:nil
                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
```

The [STTwitter library](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) can help you in using the API by mapping every endpoint to an Objective-C method.